# how to get the id from the Xpath as a text

Tags: java, selenium

I had taken the `xPath` as below but I am not able to get the value `145666` when I try to print.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='demandTrackingID']")));
```

Now iam getting the below Expception :

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='TrackID']

Note: This Html Element is a  Non Visible Element I need to inspect the panel and get this element as there is no field for this Element

HTML:

```
        <div _ngcontent-wbh-c179="" id="TrackID" class="disp-none">14566 </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML ? also what is the output ?

Comment: This is my html :

<div _ngcontent-wbh-c179="" id="ID" class="disp-none">14566
</div>

Comment: iam not getting the value  it appears as Get the Id:

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: there is no error

Comment: Can you share page url ?

Comment: @cruisepandey- THIS IS THE HTML - <span class="mat-content ng-tns-c141-334">
<mat-panel-title _ngcontent-wbh-c179="" class="mat-expansion-panel-header-title ng-tns-c141-334">
<span _ngcontent-wbh-c179="">DD ID: 41234</span>
<div _ngcontent-wbh-c179="" id="TrackID" class="disp-none">14566 </div> - Sorry iam not supposed to share the url

Comment: try the below code, and let me know if you run into issues

Comment: @jaym can you post the HTML block formatted inside the question? Currently it's not really readable

Comment: Try this once : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='14566']")).get_attribute("id")

Comment: @pmadhu -since the id is dynamic i cannot give it like this

Comment: @Prophet - have added the html

Comment: @jaym can you format if normally?

Comment: @Prophet - can you pls check  it looks like it has been formatted - Any inputs

Comment: Does the "145666" actually show on the page? The element has `class="disp-none"` which makes me think it might not be visible on the page. Selenium won't interact with invisible elements by design.

Comment: @jaym Please answer my question above. Also, you've said in comments that you've tried `WebDriverWait`. Please add that code to your question and for each code attempt, add the relevant info on what happened including any exceptions, etc. We can't help you if you don't respond with the info we need.

Comment: @jeff- as you can see i have added the wait and on running i dont get any error and it is not fetching the id

Comment: @jeff - iam now getting  - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='TrackID']... please note: this is a non visible HTML Element for which iam taking the Xpath.So basically i need to inspect the panel to get this Element

Comment: @jaym Your exception message doesn't match up with the wait code you posted... which is correct? Also, ALL CAPS doesn't help... it just looks like you're yelling.

Comment: @jeff- sorry didnt realise that i had typed in Caps so any other leads to get a solution for this

Comment: @jaym I posted an answer a while ago that you haven't commented on so I don't know whether you've tried it or if it worked, etc. I just updated my answer with an approach in case the element is not visible also.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```java
WebElement trackid= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='TrackID']"));
System.out.println("getid:"+ trackid.getText());
```

You will possible need to add an explicit wait before that to make element fully loaded before retrieving it's content

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='TrackID']")));
WebElement trackid= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-content')]//div[@id='TrackID']"));
System.out.println("getid:"+ trackid.getText());
```

Comment: no luck it is not getting the id  any other inputs

Comment: This is the HTML you provided... Maybe there is an iframe there? Have you used the `wait` as i or Jeff mentioned?

Comment: -there is no frame there.. the id is inside the panel and yes i have used wait

Comment: The `WebDriverWait` returns the element waited for so you can combine lines 2 & 3 so you don't have to hit the page again.

Comment: @JeffC :  also, it's highly unlikely that after using explicit waits, OP do not see any exception, cause explicit wait (fault) msg is TimeoutException.

Comment: @cruisepandey Agreed... I think we're missing key info from OP.

Comment: @cruisepandey Well... it depends on the wait OP used. If he used wait for visible and the element became visible but still didn't contain the desired text, there would be no exception and the code would have still failed. I still want to see all of that spelled out in the question so we can stop guessing though. I've added a new comment requesting all this under the question.

Comment: @JeffC : aight, OP is missing info to solve this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is `ID` not `id`

so use this :

```
WebElement trackid= driver.findElement(By.id("TrackID"));
System.out.println("getid:"+ trackid.getText());
```

Comment: share the error stack trace if  you see any

Answer (score 0):

The element that contains the text you want has an ID, `TrackID`, not to be confused with the "ID" text on the page. You can use that to locate the element more easily than the XPath you are currently using. Once you have the element, you can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element to contain text. Code is below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) d -> d.findElement(By.id("TrackID")).getText().length() != 0);
```

---

Given the class `class="disp-none"` on the element, I'm guessing that the element might not be visible. If this is the case, you'll have to use JavaScript to get the invisible text. Selenium was designed to only interact with visible elements and will throw an exception if you try to interact with elements that are not visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) d -> d.findElement(By.id("TrackID")).getText().length() != 0);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("TrackID"));
String trackID = (JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an approach that should work if the element is not visible on the page.

Comment: i have one issue - Lambda expression's parameter driver cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an enclosing scope. iam getting this error on the line - driver -> what should be done for this and you are saying that i need to take the xpath of the first id and then go to the Track id Xpath hope my understanding is right - @JeffC

Comment: would be helpful if i get the inputs on the question raised above

Comment: tried the code but is still not working - @JeffC

Comment: @JeffC- Thanks for the input but have used a different approach and have fixed the issue

Comment: If you've found an solution to the problem then you should probably delete this question since you no longer need an answer.